# How can I view "or 71 others" in Fitocracy quests?

Tags: fitocracy

There are some quests with a wide variety of exercises available, eg. the "Hello, Sports!" quest. It shows only some of the exercises by name and displays only the amount of the others.

I have not found a way to find out which other activities are in this list, even though the first exercises seem to rotate randomly every time you refresh the exercise tracker.

[image: exercise tracker with selected quests]

Is there a way to view those other activities?

Answer (score 1):

From the website go to: 
[www.fitocracy.com](http://www.fitocracy.com) -> click "**You**" in header tabs -> Click "**Quests**" in sidebar -> Click "**Available**" in content area.